# How to install Idea 3GNet Setter in Linux

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line, drivers

I've bought an Idea 3G Net Setter and they have provided "Linux driver" and these are the  installation details:

---

**2   Driver installation**

**2.1** Launch command line

By using “ALT+F2”, input” gnome-terminal”，click “run” button to launch command line. Shown with below screen shot:

**2.2** ROOT right needed

Root right is needed during the driver installation process. End user can start with root right from PC power on or switch to root right by command of ”su root”(switch user)before installation start. Shown with below screen shot:

**2.3** Get driver tool

Get the “driver-tool” folder ( from website or copy from datacard’s cdrom by plugin data card to Windows/MAC PC first. Eg, driver-tool got, copy to Fedora PC and put inside folder of “alcatel”.

**2.4** Start installation

Enter catalog of “driver-tool” , change file attribute by command of “chmod 777 *”. Then, execute “./tcl_instal.sh” to start the installation.

**2.5** Reboot computer

After install script executed, PC will prompt to reboot the computer. After PC reboot. Installation finished.

Plug data card to verify.
After PC reboot, plug in alcatel data card, enter “dev” folder, execute command of “ls ttyu” to list the USB device information. If the driver installation succeed, you should get information below:

If you don’t get result above, please re-install driver with above steps, then, plug in data card to query.

**3 Internet connection**

**3.1** Configure script
By execute command of “vi /etc/wvdial.conf” to configure the file of “wvdial.conf “ before start the internet connection. The APN/Dial number / password/user name need to be set. You can get above information from operator. Shown with below screen shot:

**3.2** PIN management

If PIN code is enabled, after you insert the data card to PC, please input pin code first. It will take据some time to unlock the PIN, please wait with patience. Shown with below screen shot:

**3.3** Dial up
After configure with right configuration and PIN unlocked, by executing script of “alcatel_pppd_on” to launch the internet connection. Shown with below screen shot:

**3.4** Connection succeed
Once connection succeed, will be shown with below screen shot:

**3.5** Disconnect
Run script of “alcatel_pppd_off” to disconnect the internet connection, shown with below screen shot:

---

Can anyone explain me the step 3.1 and further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's asking you to edit `/etc/wvdial.conf` to provide the APN, Dial number, username and password. You haven't provided the screenshot it mentions so I can't suggest a format.

In Ubuntu, you'll want to run `sudoedit /etc/wvdial.conf` instead though so you're editing it as root. A normal account shouldn't have permission to edit files in `/etc/`.